# 'CertOverrideService' does not contain a definition for 'GetService'

Tags: c#, .net

I wrote this code and called it in an other function but I am facing this issue:

> 'CertOverrideService' does not contain a definition for 'GetService'

```
Gecko.CertOverrideService.GetService().ValidityOverride += geckoWebBrowser1_ValidityOverride;
    
private void geckoWebBrowser1_ValidityOverride(object sender, Gecko.Events.CertOverrideEventArgs e  )  
{
    e.OverrideResult = Gecko.CertOverride.Mismatch | Gecko.CertOverride.Time | Gecko.CertOverride.Untrusted;
    e.Temporary = true;
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: Does it need the `*`?

Comment: @CyrilleConMorales I think he try to make text bolder but markup is not working inside code block

Comment: This question really needs more context to be answered. For example: What is Gecko? It seems like a framework. Probably you should refer to the documentation for that framework. However, the error message seems pretty clear. `GetService()` does not exist. There is a possibilty you need to do `GetService` *without the parentheses*.